Initialize variable for whole python package
I built a package that contains different modules.
Everything works, but i have a problem initializing a variable.
In the package,i need an init() function to initialize a variable.
How can i make this variable available in all my modules/functions?
I tried different things that only work partially.
my_package
  __init__.py
    init()
  subpackage
    my_function   <---- How to use x?


**__init.py__**
  global x
  def init(initial_value):
   global x
   x=initial_value

I want to be able to do:
import my_package
my_package.init(1234)

my_package.subpackage.my_function() <---- Should be able to use x with its 1234 value


my_package.init(1234) This is an error, because init() is defined to accept no arguments.

I think you want something like this:
init.py
def init(y):
    global x
    x=y


Sorry, there was a mistake in my description, should be clearer now
